# Laravel page load time too slow even after running artisan optimized

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2

After deploying my [website](https://www.codehub.vn) on Amazon EC2, I am having an issue with page loading time, it takes too long to process the request.

I'm pretty sure that this is the issue of the Laravel framework since I put a debug line in the beginning of `bootstrap.start.php`:

```
<?php
die();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The first thing we will do is create a new Laravel application instance
| which serves as the "glue" for all the components of Laravel, and is
| the IoC container for the system binding all of the various parts.
|
*/
```

Then it will run very fast, meaning no issue with Apache or load balancer...

But if I put the debug line just before the `return $app;`:

```
require $framework.'/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php';
die();
```

Then server takes too long time to process and exit the script and return the result to browser.

It's slow for pages even without database connection and only go through controller and then return a nearly static view.

I then tried to run this command again:

```
php artisan optimized
```

Or even tried with:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimized
```

Then the site loads the very fast for the first several requests but then after a while, it's back to slow mode.

I'm really don't how to fix this issue because the tweaks I applied at least it works but it didn't work for a long time.

The version I'm using is Laravel 4.2.

Comment: I would suspect something in your app that's loading on every request, like in `app/Services`. It's unlikely to be Laravel itself.

Comment: @ceejayoz Then it has to be slow on local (same services and plus some more), but it's not. Also then after artisan optimize it was still fast for some time.

Comment: Not necessarily - if your services are doing something like making HTTP calls on every pageview, they could be taking a long time to time out if they're calling a now-inaccessible URL, which would potentially cause the sort of behavior you're talking about.

Comment: I setup the network to block outbound request and the same thing happened

Comment: @ceejayoz pointed you in the right direction. Nobody is going to debug your entire application for you - try making minor changes. Read through your logs, see if you're throwing any errors. If you have a specific problem, people will be able to actually help here.

Answer (score 5):

After countless hours of investigation I found out the issue is not related to Laravel. It's because of the burstable CPU feature on amazon EC2 that really confuses me on debugging the app. Just change to unlimited CPU credits then it's back to normal.

Comment: it's annoying in AWS. They should show some errors based on CPU utilization. Page got hanged & can't do ssh also.